# FilterOperator bug in using quotes, same code different behavior across systems/time

Tags: sapui5

```
this.getView().getModel().read("/QualificationProficiencySet", {
    filters: [new sap.ui.model.Filter({
        path: "Qobjid",
        operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
        value1: nQObjid
    })],
    success: function(data) {
        that._profData = data.results;
        that._oQuickView.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(that._profData), "proficiencyModel");
        // delay because addDependent will do a async rerendering and the actionSheet will immediately close without it.
        jQuery.sap.delayedCall(200, that, function() {
            that._oQuickView.openBy(oLink);
        });
    },
    error: function(evt) {}
});
```

`nQObjid`is of type string - always.
Yesterday on our development system I saw the error 
`"Invalid parametertype used at function 'eq' (Position: 8)"`

I noticed that the filter was appended in the URL without single quotes around the value of `nQObjid`. Strange because at the moment it's added as the value of the filter operator it's clearly a string. I couldn't find any related issues, but I put a (dirty) workaround in place by doing `value1: "'"+nQObjid+"'"`.

This worked, until today, same system, didn't change the code, but suddenly the quotes are part of the value inside the gateway. So I remove the `"'"`again and tested, works. Then I transport the solution to production to find out that I now have the same problem on production with `"Invalid parametertype used at function 'eq'..` Another user on production does not have this issue, so I'm a bit lost.

Similar issue: [new SAPUI5 updat to 1.42 has odata bug "Invalid Parameters...](https://answers.sap.com/questions/80933/new-sapui5-updat-to-142-has-odata-bug-invalid-para.html)

Answer (score 6):

This may not solve your problem but it's too long for a comment, that's why I am posting it here:

When doing a read request, the framework is making a call to a helper class: [V2 ODataModel.js Line #4231](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel.js#L4231)

```
aUrlParams = ODataUtils._createUrlParamsArray(mUrlParams);
```

The helper class then calls a private method: [ODataUtils.js Line #72](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/ODataUtils.js#L72)

```
return "$filter=" + this._createFilterParams(aFilters, oMetadata, oEntityType);
```

This private method is doing a bunch of stuff, most importantly calling another private method which is actually building the strings [ODataUtils.js Line #128](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/ODataUtils.js#L128)

```
sFilterParam = that._createFilterSegment(oFilter.sPath, oMetadata, oEntityType, oFilterSegment.operator, oFilterSegment.value1, oFilterSegment.value2, sFilterParam);
```

One of the first thing this method does is formatting your value, and I guess here is where your problem occurs: [ODataUtils.js Line #393](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/ODataUtils.js#L393)

```
oValue1 = this.formatValue(oValue1, sType);
```

The `formatValue` function takes your value and its Edm.Type and depending on that type does different stuff. If your objectId is a string, then it should put single quotes at the beginning and the end: [ODataUtils.js Line #468](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/ODataUtils.js#L468)

```
sValue = "'" + String(vValue).replace(/'/g, "''") + "'";
```

If the type is undefined or some weird value that UI5 doesn't know, then your value is simply cast to a String (which is probably what happens in your case).

---

Why is the type undefined or weird? That's where you come in... you have to do a little debugging to find out what the actual values are. If the UI5 code is unreadable you can put `sap-ui-debug=true` as an URL parameter:

```
my.sap.system.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/ztest/index.html?sap-ui-debug=true
```

If it's a timing issue (metadata has not been loaded for whatever reasons) then wrapping your code in a `Promise` might help:

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
oModel.metadataLoaded().then(function() {
    oModel.read("/QualificationProficiencySet", {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I found that `derived entity types` will also cause `sType` to be `undefined` : https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1966